# JavaScript queue up click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long list of checkboxes like so:

```
 <input class='masterCheckbox' type='checkbox' onclick='clickAll()' />

 <input class='modifyDb' type='checkbox' onclick='ajaxCall(someId)' />
 <input class='modifyDb' type='checkbox' onclick='ajaxCall(someId)' checked />
 <input class='modifyDb' type='checkbox' onclick='ajaxCall(someId)' checked />
 ... lets say there's exactly 100 ...
 <input class='modifyDb' type='checkbox' onclick='ajaxCall(someId)' />
 <input class='modifyDb' type='checkbox' onclick='ajaxCall(someId)' />
 <input class='modifyDb' type='checkbox' onclick='ajaxCall(someId)' checked />
```

The `ajaxCall()` function makes an ajax call (using jQuery) to a PHP page to make some change in the DB.

I want the `masterCheckbox` checkbox, when checked, to go through all the unchecked checkboxes and click them all, so that they each make a separate ajax call.

Using jQuery, I managed to get all the `modifyDb` checkboxes and then with the `.each()` function called a `.click()` on each element. This works visually; the checkboxes are toggled, but the ajax call is not made.

Is this because the ajax calls are made too fast? Can I queue up the function calls somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would trigger the click event on boxes that are not already checked

```
function clickAllUnchecked(){
    $('.modyfDb').not(':checked').trigger('click')
}
```

Comment: I like the not() modifier, awesome attention to details

Answer (score 4):

Use `trigger`.
The following code reuns `onclick` of all `.modifyDb`

```
function clickAll() {
    $('.modifyDb').trigger('click');
}
```

Refference

- http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: ah, I completely forgot about trigger

Comment: Does this actually work? According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/) `.click()` is just a shortcut for `.trigger('click')`, so either should work.

Comment: The OP is already using `$.fn.click`, which simply routes to `$.fn.trigger`, FYI: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9.1/src/event-alias.js#L9

Comment: so what you're saying is that I onclick='' will not trigger?

Comment: @EliteOctagon: Actually I just checked, and it seems to work fine at triggering `onclick`. So I'm not sure why `.click()` wasn't working for you.

Comment: ok, I just read up on firing the onclick directly with $(". modifyDb")[index].onclick();

Comment: does anyone know a way of queue-ing up the function calls so that they are spaced out by say 200ms?

Answer (score 2):

I'd reorder this and get rid of all the inline event handlers. Something like this:

```
<input class='masterCheckbox' type='checkbox' />

<input class='modifyDb' type='checkbox' data-id='someId)' />
<!-- .... -->
```

And then bind them:

```
$(".modifyDb").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    ajaxCall(id);
});
```

And for the master check box:

```
$(".masterCheckbox").click(function() {
    $(".modifyDb").each(function() {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        ajaxCall(id);
        // or if you really must, you could use trigger() here
    })
});
```

Comment: this helps out quite a bit